# How to conditionally execute SQL code specific for Azure SQL Managed Instance?

Tags: azure, t-sql, azure-sql-managed-instance

I have a TSQL code where some parts are not applicable to Managed Instance. Is there a way to determine in 
TSQL code is the code executed on Managed Instance and run the code only in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') is 8 only on Managed Instance so you can use this as a condition:

```
if SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') = 8 
begin

end
else
begin

end
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance#how-to-programmatically-identify-a-managed-instance for more details.